# Setting Search Controller as Part of Navigation Item, covers the shadow image set to the navigation bar, iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11, searchbar

So after the update of iOS 11 causing the search controller to be part of the navigation item, has caused some misbehaviours of my UI.

The previous implementation was the following:

- Search Controller is set as part of the table header view.
- We set shadow image for the navigation bar, this image representing a line under the navigation bar.
- We set title View.

But with the new implementation of search controller as part of the navigation item, there is no shadow image, the line under the navigation bar. I suppose that the search controller is above this shadow image or blocking it in some way, but I am not sure.

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you